# Users unable to reach any Microsoft services (Outlook, Teams, OneDrive, Windows 10 weather)

Tags: windows-10, networking, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

For some reason two of my users (Windows 10 Pro) are unable to reach any Microsoft services. It presents itself like they have no internet connection, but everything works fine besides Microsoft products. They can access Outlook/Teams in browser just fine but not the desktop versions.

It does go away when on VPN so I'm leaning toward an adapter/setting issue...but no changes have been made that we are aware of.

What I've tried:

1. Logging into the computer as another user (works fine as another user)
2. Before I saw it was everything I did a reinstall of Office (no luck)
3. Network reset (Settings -> Network & Internet -> Network reset)
4. Other networks (only works on VPN, not wired/wireless in office or at user's home)
5. Having user log into another computer (works fine so not a MS account issue, which I wouldn't think so anyways because of the connection errors not access errors)

Edit: I did end up deleting the user's profile (System  -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> User Profile (Settings)) and that worked. I'd still like to know WHY this is occurring so we don't have to go through deleting and recreating the local profile for the users if this spreads to more users...

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Try removing/deleting MS Office credentials for those users from the control panel  -> Credentials manager. Then check if they can  use MS Office apps.

Comment: You could try to repair or reinstall Office.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I do not see any Office credentials (the only thing under Windows Credentials is "virtualapp/didlogical")

Comment: @harrymc I did try to reinstall Office with no luck

Comment: Did you check the firewall ?

Comment: @harrymc I did try turning off the firewall completely and that did not work.

Comment: As stated in my edit I was able to correct the issue by deleting the user's profile and recreating it. This isn't the most elegant solution so if anyone knows why this is occurring and a quicker way to correct it I'd still like to know...

Comment: Corrupted profiles are almost impossible to analyze.

Comment: Deleted corrupted profiles are actually impossible to diagnose…

Comment: What's the version of your Office? Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version. And is there any error prompt when you cannot connect?

Comment: @Christy Microsoft 365 Apps for business, 2208. Everything is updated as far as I can tell, the users are running the same versions I am. 

The Windows 10 "News and interests" widget shows "We're having trouble loading your feed. You might be offline, or there could be something happening on our end".

Office errors include "No Network Connection. Please check your network settings and try again. [2603]" and "Try that again. Page could not be loaded. Please try again later. Code: 0x80131500"

Comment: Did you ever figure out anything more on this? After a Windows update, anything with a Microsoft online authentication decided to stop working (Outlook - Exchange, Teams, Windows Store, OneDrive, Windows "Family", even SmartScreen.) While browsing and everything else seems to work fine.

Comment: @Ben in CA The only thing we have found that works is going to (in Win10) Windows Key -> Search "Proxy settings" -> Turn on "User a proxy server" under "Manual proxy setup" then turn it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Logging into the computer as another user (works fine as another user)

> Having user log into another computer (works fine so not a MS account issue, which I wouldn't think so anyways because of the connection errors not access errors)

Based on your description, I noticed that the problem seems to be related only to the profiles configured on the current user's computer. I'm afraid that at the moment it can only be solved by deleting the old profile and re-creating the new one.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: I agree that it is a solution, as it worked with one of the users and I will be trying the same with another user, but there must be something with the profile that can be fixed without deletion/recreation as it is very disruptive to the user. I'm inclined to mark it as a solution since it does resolve the issue and no one else seems to have any ideas, but so would provisioning them a new computer, not really a "fix".

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue multiple times on one Windows 10 computer in my home but not the other one nor 2 laptops. I used my phone to mobile hotspot in, again signed into the Fix My Account message in Outlook and it's all fine for now. I've tried all the other fixes to no avail except creating more profiles. I refuse to go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).