# Various Microsoft authentication failing to connect on user profile after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, microsoft

After Windows doing an automatic update, anything with a Microsoft online authentication decided to stop working on my computer (Outlook - Exchange, Teams, Windows Store, OneDrive, Windows "Family", even SmartScreen.)

Yet browsing and everything else seems to work fine. I rely on Outlook and Teams a lot, so really need them to work.

I've tried a pile of things including reverting the Windows update, doing a network reset, system restore (failed), etc.

I setup another user profile, and it works fine there - so it's not a network issue. (That rules out a lot.)

However, there's a zillion customizations I have on my user profile; I'm really hoping there's something that I can just tweak vs. moving everything to a new profile.

A new user profile is practically as disruptive as a wipe/reload.

Somewhat similar to this issue:
[Users unable to reach any Microsoft services (Outlook, Teams, OneDrive, Windows 10 weather)](https://superuser.com/q/1742190/1171064)

Anyone have any ideas?

[image: Can't connect]

Yes, I can ping login.microsoftonline.com
[image: Ping]

Comment: I setup another user profile, and it works fine there -   ....  So at this point, replace the current User Profile.   They cannot be repaired.

Comment: @John - Everything can be repair until it can't.

Comment: @BeninCA - Are you able to ping `login.microsoftonline.com.com` what DNS servers are you using? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: It is almost always easier and faster to replace a User Profile than to find the needle in the haystack causing the problem.

Comment: For a regular user account, yes, just replace it. But for a power user, it's a last resort type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had nearly the same issue happen in my new profile about 10 days later... after an automatic Office 365 update.

Tried reinstalling Teams again, etc. and no go. (Oddly, this time Outlook still worked.)

Found something online saying to try Resetting all Internet Explorer settings. Did that, and that fixed it. Even though I don't use Internet Explorer, nor had changed any settings there.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Great share! You can accept your own post as answer after waiting 48 hours : )

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just replacing the user profile.

Really odd issue though, and there's likely a much easier fix, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In case the issue occurs again, you can try adding the registry keys below on the affected machine:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity]

"EnableADAL"=dword:00000000

"DisableADALatopWAMOverride"=dword:00000001

"DisableAADWAM"=dword:00000001
```

Here's a similar thread for reference: [FIX: Error connecting Outlook to M365 (HTTP 404 login.microsoftonline.com)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/fix-error-connecting-outlook-to-m365-http-404/bef8d6c5-a5c4-498b-ac72-bc81defb8256)

Comment: I tried this when something similar happened again in my new profile ~ 10 days later. But this time Outlook was working (but not Teams, etc.), and it killed Outlook too when I did that.